# Unable to load JSON in EXTJS multi-select

Tags: javascript, servlets, extjs

I am unable to display the entries in multi-select box in EXTJS. Here is my code for EXTJS multi-select and corresponding panel:

```
var selectTrain = [{
    bodyStyle: 'padding:10px;',
    items:[{
        xtype: 'multiselect',
        fieldLabel: 'Multiselect',
        name: 'multiselect',
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        id: 'selectTrain',
        store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            type: 'ajax',
            url:'http://abc.com/xyz',
            reader: 'json',
            autoLoad:true      
        }),
        ddReorder: true
    }]
}];


// combine all that into one huge form
var fp = new Ext.FormPanel({
    title: '',
    frame: true,
    labelWidth: 300,
    width: 800,
    renderTo:'report',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:0 10px 0;',
    items: [
        {
            layout: 'column',
            border: false,
            // defaults are applied to all child items unless otherwise specified by child item
            defaults: {
                columnWidth: '1',
                border: false
            },            
            items: [selectTrain]
        },
    ],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Go',
        handler: function(){}
    },{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function(){
            fp.getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
});
```

I am able to hit the URL http://abc.com/xyz which is a servlet and see the following JSON being written on the Firebug console:

```
{"54850":"5.1(1t)d1(3)","54852":"5.1(1t)a2(3)","54853":"5.1(1t)l2(1)","54841":"1.2(4)S1(1)","54789":"5.3(1)T","54849":"5.1(1t)s1(2)","54854":"5.1(1t)l2(5)","54855":"5.1(1t)s2(6)","54847":"1.1(12a)SG"}
```

The servlet code for http://abc.com/xyz is:

```
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject();
           for (Iterator iterator = allRelInfoPools.iterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
               Vector v = (Vector) iterator.next();
               jsonObj.put((String)v.get(0),(String)v.get(1));

    }
           out.println(jsonObj);
```

Pls advise, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to make a cross-domain AJAX request (eg, you're app was loaded from http://def.com/, but you're trying to load the JSON from http://abc.com/xyz). This, unfortunately, is not allowed.

However, you can do a JSONP request instead of an AJAX request. What JSONP does is inject a script tag into the DOM, and it will force it to download a JavaScript file that will hold your JSON data in it. You should then be able to retrieve your data.

Fortunately, EXTJS allows you to do just that. In *your* code, for example, just change the `type` property of the `store` from `ajax` to `jsonp`.

And also, change the servlet code to "pad" the `jsonObj` variable with a JavaScript function call based on the `callback` GET query (note, the `callback` GET query is retrieved when a GET request was made via a URL like so: http://abc.com/xyz?callback=someCallbackFunction).

Here's how your last line should look like:

```
out.println(callbackParam + "(" + jsonObj + ");");
```

Where the `callbackParam` is the value you got from the `callback` parameter from the GET query.